# Is R 3.6 kernel available for Fedora?

Tags: fedora, r

I use **Fedora 29** and I try to install **M3C** package (Monte Carlo simulation) from Bioconductor but it requires **R 3.6** version.

I ran `sudo yum install R` and it still downloads 3.5.3 "Great Truth".

Anything I can do to benefit from **R 3.6** (without changing OS obviously...)